# Javascript sub-string search

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a basic text search for a div using an input box but I can only get it to work if I enter the exact full word, how would I modify this code to work for a sub-string e.g. if I enter Test I would like to return both Test and Test2 or Just T should return both etc?

```js
//search site for pages
     function search_sitemap() { 
     let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value 
     input=input.toLowerCase(); 
            let x = document.getElementsByClassName('pages'); 
            var urls = [];

            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
                // make an array of strings
                var words = x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().split(",");
              if (!words.includes(input)) { 
             x[i].style.display="none"; 
         } 
          else { 

                    x[i].style.display = "block";  
                    urls.push(x[i].href);
                 
         } 
            }

            return urls;
      }   
         

  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head></head>

<body>
 <header></header>

  <!--searchbar-->
     <button class="searchbtn"><img src="Images\search.png" id="s-icon">
     <div id='searchlist'>
      <a class="pages" href="test.html" style="display:none;">Test</a></li>
          <a class="pages" href="test2.html" style="display:none;">Test2</a></li>
      <a class="pages" href="best.html" style="display:none;">Best</a></li>
      <a class="pages" href="rest.html" style="display:none;">Rest</a></li>
   </div>
   </button>    
     <div class="searchbar">
      <input type="text" id="searchbar" onkeyup="search_sitemap()" placeholder="" value="Search.." maxlenght="25" autocomplete="off" onMouseDown="active();" onBlur="inactive()" />
     </div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW, a `button` isn't allowed to contain `div` elements.

Comment: Cheers sorted that out!

Answer (score 0):

You could check if *some* of the words *start with* the search:

```
words.some(word => word.startsWith(input))
```

Comment: Perfect thanks Jonas that works great all I needed to do was swap my conditions around to go with your search!